# Saving double RDD into file - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to save in a file a double RDD, what I mean by a double RDD is that I have this variable:

```
res: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String,String), Int)]] = MapPartitionsRDD[19]
```

I tried to store it with

```
res.saveAsTextFile(path)
```

But it doesn't work, an exception is launched because Spark does not support nested RDD here is a sample of the code:

```
val res = Listword.map { x =>
Listword.map { y =>
  ((x._1, y._1), x._2 + y._2)
}
}
res.saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? If possible, add a small fragment of code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You cannot have nested RDDs, you can work around joining them somehow.

Comment: Seems like a job for cartesian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark does not allow nested RDDs. In your specific case, you can use `cartesian`:

```
ListWord.cartesian(ListWord).map { case (x, y) =>
  ((x._1, y._1), x._2 + y._2)
}
```